# What are good Morse Theory lecture notes and books?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, textbook-recommendation, morse-theory

Searching on the net I couldnt find any recent lecture/course notes on Morse Theory. I found an old set of notes (http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/Morse%20Theory/mfp.pdf) by Mike Hutchings and these incomplete notes by Ralph Cohen (http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/morsecourse/biglectures.pdf)

[..I really want a reference which has a detailed description of the ``gradient flow line" perspective as in the chater 4,5,6 of Ralph's notes. Just that Ralph's notes are very hard to follow given that all the diagrams are missing!..]

I found this book that has been made legally freely available by the author, https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf and I have read quite a bit of the old book by Milnor.

- Are there other other good references (particularly lecture/course notes) that I am missing?

Comment: Looking for freebies is not in the scope.

Comment: @IgorRivin, although I agree that "looking for freebies" doesn't sound good, perhaps "looking for freely-available sources" sounds ok? In my own life, I've exerted a good bit of effort to generate "freely available" (and reasonably high quality) documents available... and I have a tendency to think that all academic mathematicians should do so... The possibility of vulgar-sounding references doesn't deter me. :)

Comment: Morse homology by Schwarz. Also another one by Audin-Damian (might have misspelled). These are the typical references now (and then a book by Banyaga). But Hutchings’ notes are amazing ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Seems surprising that no one has written lecture/course notes on this topic!

Comment: It might help if you let us know what precisely you would like to learn.  Morse theory is discussed in many places.

Comment: As I said in the post, the "gradient flow line" perspective in chapters 4,5 and 6 (and others) in Ralph's notes is what I am really after..

Comment: @gradstudent: I feel there are many lecture notes on the subject...

Comment: Look at these notes https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf  Floer homology is discussed  in Sec 2.5.  Chapter 4 is devoted to a rather detailed investigation  of the gradient flow dynamics. In particular it is hown that the Morse-Smale condition is equivalent to the fact  that the stratification by unstable manifolds is a Whitney stratification.  This leads  to a more sophisticated view of the Floer homology in Sec 4.5.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Your freely available book is indeed a huge help!

Comment: Rather than reading a book, a great way to learn Morse Theory is to use it in some "readily computable" cases.  For example, the electrostatic potential function on configuration spaces is a lovely Bott-style Morse function (most of the time).  Working out the flowlines and handle attachments in things like $C_k D^n$ for $k=2,3,4$ is a lovely learning experience.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are looking for the classical approach to Morse theory, I feel nothing beats Milnor's book on the subject:

> Milnor, J.
>   Morse theory. 
>   Annals of Mathematics Studies, No. 51 Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J. 1963

For the Morse homological approach, i.e. counting flowlines, I really like Weber's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411465)  on the subject:

> Weber, Joa
>   The Morse-Witten complex via dynamical systems. 
>   Expo. Math. 24 (2006), no. 2.

Another standard reference is the book of Banyaga and Hurtubise.

> Banyaga, Augustin; Hurtubise, David
>   Lectures on Morse homology. 
>   Kluwer Texts in the Mathematical Sciences, 29. Kluwer Academic Publishers Group, Dordrecht, 2004.

A book that is tough to read, but is a gateway to Floer theory is Schwarz' book.

> Schwarz, Matthias
>   Morse homology. 
>   Progress in Mathematics, 111. Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel, 1993.

I heard good things about the book of Audin and Damian, but I have not read it.

> Audin, Michèle; Damian, Mihai
>   Morse theory and Floer homology. 
>   Translated from the 2010 French original by Reinie Erné. Universitext. Springer, London; EDP Sciences, Les Ulis, 2014.

Answer (score 7):

These [lecture notes](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F1-4020-4266-3_01) were actually mainly devoted to the Morse Complex in the infinite dimensional setting; but they were thought to be suitable for finite dimensional manifolds as well (btw, you don't need to pay for [them](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.577.8875&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Comment: Many thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 2):

Another classic text is Bott's [Lectures on Morse theory, old and new](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183549637).

Answer (score 1):

also in the [M. W. Hirsch, Differential topology](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9449-5) ,Chapter 6 : Morse Theory.